# ajax function not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

> the code runs up to alert("name"+name+"type"+type) and alerts the user inputs successfully, but does not execute the ajax function is there any syntax error in this code or am i missing something or doing something wrong like missing $ or $(function()) etc anything thats requirement for ajax to get executed

```
function myfunction() {

        var checkedName = document.querySelector('input[name="case-type"]:checked'),
        checkedType = document.querySelector('input[name="state-name"]:checked'),
        name = checkedName ? checkedName.value : "Nothing selected",
        type = checkedType ? checkedType.value : "Nothing selected"
    alert("name"+ name + "Type" + type);

$.ajax({// defining the below function as ajax responsive//
    url:'TypeState', // the function that process the  mapped url name and matching type is going to receive the data//
    type:'POST',
    data:{state_name:name,case_type:type},// function to get the value from jsp page and send it to mapped class function//
    success: function(response){// if the backend process is success then the function will run by getting the response as its parameter//
            alert(response.message);
```

Comment: Any errors in browser console? did you try adding error handler to `$.ajax`?

Comment: nothing is getting printed in console my eclipse debugger is not working properly brother

Comment: @charlietfl yes brother error handler is there but still its the same the code does not even getting transfered to back end controller

Comment: So add an error handler , that's what they are for. Beyond that there simply isn't enough shown for us to know why

Comment: @charlietfl yes brother error handler is there but still its the same the code does not even getting transfered to back end controller

Comment: So what are the details from the error handler?

Comment: error: function(response){
     alert("unable to pull up any electricians or plumbers for the selected state");
       } 
 });

Comment: That alert is meaningless. Inspect the arguments of error handler

Comment: @charlietfl the code does not execute the ajax function at all so the error handler is not printing anything

Comment: is the function being called by a form control or form submit? Sounds like form is submitting using default form process

Comment: yes it does matter because form submit will close out current page

Comment: @charlietfl yes bro function my function is being called by a sumbit button

Comment: Please show how. You need to prevent the default action of that button or change it's type to "button"

Comment: @charlietfl oh wow bro may be that could be why, could you please tell me how i should modify it bro, im really a newbie to this

Comment: @charlietfl thanks bro i will try that

Comment: It is definitely why....and you should be seeing the page reload as a result of the form submitting which is what you wanted to avoid by using the ajax